# How to Remove Customer Account Navigation Links in OpenCart

Tags: twig, opencart, opencart-3

[image: Problem]

I tried everything but still can't remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Templates for all accounts module: `\catalog\view\theme\default\template\account`

For your page: `\catalog\view\theme\default\template\account\account.twig`

[image]

Comment: I removed all of it but the navigation links still appears, what to do now ?

Comment: @user3081704 reset cache...?

Comment: Yes i did that too, but still the links are displaying